# Xamarin- No se muestra botones ni texto

Tags: android, xamarin, interfaz-gráfica

Acabo de descargar Xamarin para Visual Studio por primera vez, conecte mi tableta Inco. Cree una proyecto Blank App(android) y en el main.axml arrastre un botón y un texto, pero cuando ejecute la aplicación en mi tableta solo se veía el nombre de la solución junto con el logo por defecto, un fondo negro y nada más, sin boton ni texto.
Aunque en el modo design del main.axml si se ven claramente
No se mostraron errores al compilar.
Configure en Properties la correcta version de android que usa mi tableta KitKat.
¿Alguien podria ayudarme a solucionar este problema?

Como se ve en el main.axml

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en la tablet se ve asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<Button
    android:text="Hello World"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="68.0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0.0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="92.0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="62.0dp" />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:text="nanana" /></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Por favor incluye el código generado por la herramienta cuando arrastraste los componentes. Eso nos ayudaría a revisar qué puede estar pasando en la aplicación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya encontre el error, no se como pero faltaba esta linea en MainActivity.cs
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

Comment: Ami me pasaba igual gracias por compartir tu solución, saludos.